# Remove trailing slash in WP multisite .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, wordpress, trailing-slash

I've created an .htaccess file that contains redirects for one site that is part of a larger WordPress Multisite install.

The .htaccess content starts with this (necessary because the same .httacess file must be used for multiple sites:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com [nc]
```

And then contains a series of rewrites, like so:

```
RewriteRule ^about-my-site$ about [R=301,NC,L]
```

If I visit `mydomain.com/about-my-site`, I am correctly redirected to `mydomain.com/about`
However, if I visit `mydomain.com/about-my-site/` (please note trailing slash), I get a "Page not found" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your RewriteRule to

```
RewriteRule ^about-my-site/?$ about [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: Change to [R,NC] temporarily and check where you're being redirected.

Comment: Your original suggestion worked. Sorry for the confusion. Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

These rules should go before your WordPress rules, make sure that rewriting is on, and set a rewrite base of `/` -

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^about-my-site/? about [R=301,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Test here: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

```
input url
http://mydomain.com/about-my-site/

output url
http://mydomain.com/about

debugging info
1 RewriteEngine On  
2 RewriteBase / 
3 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mydomain.com [NC]        This condition was met
4 RewriteRule ^about-my-site/? about [R=301,NC,L]   This rule was met, the new url is http://mydomain.com/about
Test are stopped, because of the R in your RewriteRule options. A redirect will be made with status code 301
```

Comment: +1 for sharing the test site. I used to test on my local Apache. Thanks.